# Mutex does not seem to be locking properly

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

I am just learning about mutexess.  I thought the following program would return a total of 1000, but I am getting varied results, so I assume I am doing something wrong...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var total int
var locker sync.RWMutex

func add() {
    for x := 1; x <= 100; x++ {
        locker.Lock()
        total += 1
        locker.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    for x := 1; x <= 10; x++ {
        go add()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Total is %v\n", total)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main function returns before gorutines finished their works, you should add `sync.WaitGroup`, this code works as you expected: https://play.golang.com/p/_OfrZae0soB

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var total int
var locker sync.RWMutex

func add(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for x := 1; x <= 100; x++ {
        locker.Lock()
        total += 1
        locker.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for x := 1; x <= 10; x++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go add(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Total is %v\n", total)
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting for any of the goroutines you started to *finish* before checking the result. Use a `WaitGroup` to wait for all of them to complete.

Comment: Thanks.  I only gave the other answer the tick as it showed an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a data race. Therefore, the results are undefined.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var total int
var locker sync.RWMutex

func add() {
    for x := 1; x <= 100; x++ {
        locker.Lock()
        total += 1
        locker.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    for x := 1; x <= 10; x++ {
        go add()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Total is %v\n", total)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x0000005ba408 by main goroutine:
  runtime.convT2E64()
      /home/peter/go/src/runtime/iface.go:335 +0x0
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:23 +0x84

Previous write at 0x0000005ba408 by goroutine 14:
  main.add()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:14 +0x76

Goroutine 14 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:21 +0x52
==================
Total is 960
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about the -race option... I'll look into that.